# mssql php can't select field type nvarchar(MAX)

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I use this code to select password field from the sql server 2012 db, and does not return any data
I tried to change the field type and it did work
actually I can't change the field type in the main server and I need to work with it as it is

any idea how to work around it?

```
<?php
$objConnect = mssql_connect("localhost:1434\MSSQLSERVER","fdi","fdifdi");

if($objConnect)  
{  
echo "Database Connected.<br />";  
mssql_select_db('Intranett', $objConnect);
$query = mssql_query('SELECT  [pass] FROM [Intranett].[dbo].[v24Brukere]');

// Check if there were any records
if (!mssql_num_rows($query)) {
    echo 'No records found';
} else {
    // Print a nice list of users in the format of:
    // * name (username)

    echo '<ul>';

    while ($row = mssql_fetch_object($query)) {
        echo '<li>' . $row->pass .' </li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}

}  
else  
{  
echo "Database Connect Failed.<br />";  
echo mssql_get_last_message();
}  

mssql_close($objConnect);  
?>
```

Comment: whay don't you nvarchar(100) or something instead of nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: Are you using the most appropriate [drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)?

Comment: I can't change the type field on the server, I have to use it as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `NVARCHAR` is not supported with the old and long outdated mssql-drivers. You should instead use [Microsoft's SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

Comment: Yes, SQLSRV and PDO_SQLSRV (both included in the zip) you can use nvarchar-fields.

Comment: @OZ_ Accessing SQL Server from a Linux -machine is admittedly trickier. You should use pdo_odbc with FreeTDS. Microsoft offers an "ODBC driver for Linux", which is quite new, so I can't say if this will work: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160